# Find all files matching metadata tag

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, view, folder

We have a document library with multiple folders for each organisation (each organisation can only access their own folder). We have templates in each folder with metadata such as "Document description"

As a user who needs to see everything, this folder structure is not the best to work with. Needing to click on each sub-folder is time consuming.

is it possible to create a view where central users can select "Report X" and see all documents with this tag in all the subfolders? I have tried dynamic filtering but it doesn't seem possible with sub-folders. Are there any alternatives? I need sub-folders to control access to documents as different organisations are updating templates and should not see each others documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new document library view with all files & without subfolders,

You can modify the current view and select "Show all items without folders" under the **Folders** section:

[image]

You can also apply filters to show document based on column values under **Filters** section on view settings page:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)